# Use Implicit differentiation to prove $y'' =\frac {-9}{y^2}$ if $4x^2-2y^2= 9$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Having trouble with this calculus question if someone could walk it through step by step I'd greatly appreciate it.

Use Implicit differentiation to prove  $y'' =\frac {-9}{y^2}$ if $4x^2-2y^2= 9$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! When creating questions, it is generally a good idea to also include what you have tried so far, or to say what you know about the problem.

Comment: This is not a "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that $$y=y(x)$$ is given then we get
$$8x-4yy'=0$$

Answer (score 0):

differentiate both sides of: $4x^2 - 2y^2 = 9$

$\frac d{dx}(4x^2 - 2y^2 = 9)\\
8x - 4yy' = 0$

If you don't understand why $\frac {d}{dx} y^2 = 2yy'$ then you need to talk to your teacher / TA / tutor to explain the concept of implicit differentiation again.  If that is the case don't stress, it is a little slippery.

isolate $y'$

$y' = \frac {2x}{y}$

Now differentiate again (with respect to x) to find $y''$

$y'' = \frac {2y - 2xy'}{y^2}$

and substitute the value of $y'$ found above.

$y'' = \frac {2y - 2x\frac {2x}{y}}{y^2}\\
y'' = \frac {2y^2 - 4x^2}{y^3}$

and $2y^2 - 4x^2 = -9$ from the original constraint.

$y'' = \frac {-9}{y^3}$

And your proposition is not true!